# send the form information to my email box with php

Tags: php, jquery

```
<input type="button" class="button" />
<form action="" method="">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" email="email" />
<input type="text" phone="phone" />
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

1,click the button, then popup the form, after the user fills out all the information in the form than click the submit button, send all the form information to my eamil box.

how to write the action part. and which method  should i use? should i use mail function to send the email or other ways?

i may use jquery to pop up the form window, but i don't know how to collect the form information,then send it my email box.

Comment: An end-to-end form to email tutorial is overly broad for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: `action="mailto:youraccount@example.com"` used to work. haven't tried it any modern browsers though.

Comment: @MarcB — That has never worked reliably.

Comment: @quentin: and for good reason. it was one way for malicious sites to steal your email address.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very broad question, but in a nutshell this is how it is done:

Post the form to a php file that will handle it and use PHP `mail()` function to send it:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
```

process.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)):
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value):
    $message = "$key : $value \n";
    endforeach;
mail('mymail@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post it then send the email. Also, `<input type="text" email="email" />` needs to be `<input type="text" name="email" />` need to use the name attribute.

Try this:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)){
        $send_message = 'Name: ' . $_POST[name] . ' Email: ' . $_POST[email] . ' Phone: ' . $_POST[phone] . ' Message: ' . $_POST[message];
        mail('youremail@email.com', 'Subject', $send_message); 
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` before **emailing** it?!

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the heads up. I edited it. I'm use to doing queries when I post.